# How can we write to local disk (ie on files on the client) using Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I need to save some data from a Chrome Extension either to a local disk file or Google Spreadsheets. The problem I am facing is being able to find a right solution for writing to files using javascript since it is considered to be a security hole and generally not adviced. I need help in figuring on a method to write to local files using Javascript (if it is possible in the first place  or else please suggest and alternative to this (like any method on how to save data from an extension to Google Spreadsheet).

Thanks in advance

Comment: not possible, but with html5 you can store 5mb locally

Answer (score 3):

You can't for security reasons. If you could, this would be the ultimate back-door.

Comment: Extensions are not webpages. They are things users install, not pages they visit.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think the Javascript cares what it's being used in.

Comment: JavaScript uses whatever APIs are made available to it. Web browsers do not give file writing APIs to JavaScript embedded in a web page. Browser extensions are another story. SSJS implementations are another story. JScript (which as pretty much JavaScript aside from a name change for trandmark reasons) in Windows Scripting Host is another story.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a [signed java applet](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/signed.html). [You can also delete/modify/anything user's files].

Comment: You can call into this applet with javascript, or call into javascript from the applet.